# How to post ng-repeat Object data? i tried this way but not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How to post ng-repeat Object data? i tried this way but not working.

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as MC">
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="(item,value) in MC.items">
        {{item}} <input type="text" ng-model="value"/>
    </div>
</div>
<button ng-click="MC.submitMe()">Save</button>
```

Controller:

```
mc.items = {prompt: 'prompt 1', value: 'value 1'};

mc.submitMe = function(){
    var url = 'http://serverUrl';

    //sample post code:
    //$http.post(url, self.items);

    //debug:
    alert('post data to ' + url + '\n' + JSON.stringify(mc.items));
};
```

Comment: Instead of self.items use mc.items

Answer (score 0):

From the [AngularJs Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

in your case you are missing the callback functions:

```
$http.post(url, mc.items).then(function successCallback(response) {
  alert('post data to ' + url + '\n' + JSON.stringify(mc.items));

}, function errorCallback(response) {
  alert('post failed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as MC">
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="(item,value) in MC.items">
        {{item}} <input type="text" ng-model="MC.items[item]"/>
    </div>
</div>
<button ng-click="MC.submitMe()">Save</button>

Change your ng-model as above
```